# sufficient condition for the continuity of conditional probability wrt the conditioning variable

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Given a regular conditional probability $P(X\in B | T(X) = t)$, where $T$ is a continuous mapping from $\mathcal{X}$ (on which $X$ is defined) to $\mathcal{T}$. Do we know any sufficient condition for such conditional probability to be continuous with respect to $t$? For simplicity one may assume extra structures, such as $\mathcal{T} = \mathbb{R}^d$ (I would like to keep $\mathcal{X}$ to be at least Hilbertian), $T$ is surjective on $\mathcal{T}$, etc.

Related question:[Disintegrations are measurable measures - when are they continuous?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15853/disintegrations-are-measurable-measures-when-are-they-continuous)

Comment: Does the answer to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13292 answer your question?

Comment: @RHahn no, I'm looking into the continuity with respect to the conditioning, namely if the probability changes continuous with the change of the level set of conditioning.

Comment: I see you found the actual question I meant to link to, which seems much closer to what you are asking. I don't have anything to add beyond the answers given there, in particular the Tjur article may be helpful. I hope you can get an answer.